# HeapWalk not working as expected in Release mode

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

So I used [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee175819%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example of the HeapWalk function to implement it into my app. I played around with it a bit and saw that when I added

```
HANDLE d = HeapAlloc(hHeap, 0, sizeof(int));
int* f = new(d) int;
```

after creating the heap then some new output would be logged:

```
Allocated block  Data portion begins at: 0X037307E0
  Size: 4 bytes
  Overhead: 28 bytes
  Region index: 0
```

So seeing this I thought I could check `Entry.wFlags` to see if it was set as `PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY` to keep a track of how much allocated memory I'm using on the heap. So I have:

```
HeapLock(heap);

int totalUsedSpace = 0, totalSize = 0, largestFreeSpace = 0, largestCounter = 0;

PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY entry;
entry.lpData = NULL;
while (HeapWalk(heap, &entry) != FALSE)
{
    int entrySize = entry.cbData + entry.cbOverhead;

    if ((entry.wFlags & PROCESS_HEAP_ENTRY_BUSY) != 0)
    {
        // We have allocated memory in this block
        totalUsedSpace += entrySize;
        largestCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // We do not have allocated memory in this block
        largestCounter += entrySize;
        if (largestCounter > largestFreeSpace)
        {
            // Save this value as we've found a bigger space
            largestFreeSpace = largestCounter;
        }
    }

    // Keep a track of the total size of this heap
    totalSize += entrySize;
}

HeapUnlock(heap);
```

And this appears to work when built in debug mode (`totalSize` and `totalUsedSpace` are different values). However, when I run it in Release mode `totalUsedSpace` is always 0.

I stepped through it with the debugger while in Release mode and for each heap it loops three times and I get the following flags in `entry.wFlags` from calling `HeapWalk`:

```
1 (PROCESS_HEAP_REGION)
0
2 (PROCESS_HEAP_UNCOMMITTED_RANGE)
```

It then exits the `while` loop and GetLastError() returns `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS` as expected.

From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9898/Heap-Walker) I found that a flag value of `0` is "the committed block which is free, i.e. not being allocated or not being used as control structure."

Does anyone know why it does not work as intended when built in Release mode? I don't have much experience of how memory is handled by the computer, so I'm not sure where the error might be coming from. Searching on Google didn't come up with anything so hopefully someone here knows.

UPDATE: I'm still looking into this myself and if I monitor the app using vmmap I can see that the process has 9 heaps, but when calling `GetProcessHeaps` it returns that there are 22 heaps. Also, none of the heap handles it returns matches to the return value of `GetProcessHeap()` or `_get_heap_handle()`. It seems like `GetProcessHeaps` is not behaving as expected. Here is the code to get the list of heaps:

```
// Count how many heaps there are and allocate enough space for them
DWORD numHeaps = GetProcessHeaps(0, NULL);
HANDLE* handles = new HANDLE[numHeaps];

// Get a handle to known heaps for us to compare against
HANDLE defaultHeap = GetProcessHeap();
HANDLE crtHeap = (HANDLE)_get_heap_handle();

// Get a list of handles to all the heaps
DWORD retVal = GetProcessHeaps(numHeaps, handles);
```

And `retVal` is the same value as `numHeaps`, which indicates that there was no error.

Comment: Are you using HeapLock and HeapUnlock before and after HeapWalk?

Comment: Yes, I omitted the code around the actual `HeapWalk` function for brevity. I'll add them in to the snippet

Comment: Do you inspect variables (including `totalUsedSpace`) with debugger or you wrote them to debugger console/stdout/file? Because debugger may lie about variable contents when inspecting Release builds.

Comment: The values are being written out to a text file.

Comment: I'm still looking into this myself and if I monitor the app using vmmap I can see that the process has 9 heaps, but when calling `GetProcessHeaps` it returns that there are 22 heaps. Also, none of the heap handles it returns matches to the return value of `GetProcessHeap()` or `_get_heap_handle()`. It seems like `GetProcessHeaps` is not behaving as expected.

Comment: I've updated the original post to include more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Verifier had been set up previously to do a full page heap verifying of my executable and was interfering with the heaps returned by `GetProcessHeaps`. I'd forgotten about it being set up as it was done for a different issue several days ago and then closed without clearing the tests. It wasn't happening in debug build because the application builds to a different file name for debug builds.

We managed to detect this by adding a breakpoint and looking at the callstack of the thread. We could see the AV DLL had been injected in and that let us know where to look.